# How do I use .getText() for Selenium WebDriver on element.By(css())?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

**SOLVED**
This did the trick.

```
const text = await browser.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText();
assert.equal(text, "About me");
```

Trying to test my frontend with Selenium WebDriver.
I want to test the `<h1>` element, but the .getText() is not receiving any content.

The server and the local webpage is running, there are no more h1 elements.

This is the setup:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const { Builder, By } = require("selenium-webdriver");

const Firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const firefoxOptions = new Firefox.Options().headless();

const URL = "http://192.168.1.99:3000/#!/";

let browser;
```

I have a before all tests I want to connect and build the website.

```
    beforeEach(async function() {
        this.timeout(20000);

        browser = await new Builder(Firefox)
            .forBrowser('firefox')
            .setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions)
            .build();

        await browser.get(URL);

    });
```

And then the test

```
    // Test case
    it("Test index", async () => {

        const element = await browser.findElement(By.css("h1"));
        const text = await element.getText();

        await assert.equal(text, "About me");

    });
```

I get the result

```
  0 passing (5s)
  1 failing

  1) Test Me-app
       Test index:

      AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: '' == 'About me'
      + expected - actual

      +About me

      at Context.it (test/src/MochaTest.js:67:22)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I run it all with **mocha** doing `npm test`

A console.log of the `text` shows it is empty.
Selenium docs says

> this.getText() → Promise
>   Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

But how do I then get the text?

Comment: run your page, open devtools and see if the selector works. F12 and in console type: `document.querySelector("h1").textContent` chek if it returns "About me".

Comment: @Moro yes, checked it and it returns "About me".

Comment: Can you debug it with breakpoint on `await text` line or just place a delay there? If it does not work with a timeout, maybe `assert.equal(browser.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText(), "About me");` will work ;)

Comment: @Moro I added another await to your code and it worked... `assert.equal(await browser.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText(), "ABOUT ME")`.

Comment: `await assert.equal(browser.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText(), "About me");` does this help? Connection is fine, it is my lack of JavaScript knowledge : p

Comment: @Moro Thanks!!! It was something with actually doing it in two awaits that caused the problem!